# If $f\in C([a,b])$, $V(f^2;[a,b])<\infty$, then $V_2(f;[a,b]) \leq C(V(f^2;[a,b])+\|f\|_\infty^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis, bounded-variation

> Assume that $f\in C([a,b])$ is a complex-valued function with $V(f^2;[a,b])<\infty$. Prove that $$V_2(f;[a,b])\leq C(V(f^2;[a,b])+\|f\|_\infty^2),$$ where $C>0$ is independent of $a,b$ and $f$.

Note that $V(f;[a,b])$ denotes the total variation of $f$ on $[a,b]$:
$$V(f;[a,b]):=\sup_{a=a_0<a_1<\cdots a_k=b}\sum_{j=1}^k|f(a_j)-f(a_{j-1})|.$$
$V_2(f;[a,b])$ denotes the quadratic variation of $f$ on $[a,b]$:
$$V_2(f;[a,b]):=\sup_{a=a_0<a_1<\cdots a_k=b}\sum_{j=1}^k|f(a_j)-f(a_{j-1})|^2.$$

I can only prove the inequality $V_2(f;[a,b])\leq 2V(f^2;[a,b])$ for real-valued $f$, by first showing $V_2(f;[a,b])\leq 2V_2(|f|;[a,b])$, thanks to the continuity of $f$, and then showing $V_2(|f|;[a,b])\leq V(f^2;[a,b])$. Both steps are consequences of the definitions and require the function to be real-valued. In the first step, the IVT (for real-valued functions) is used; and in the second step, I use the fact that $\sqrt x$ is $1/2-$H$\ddot{\text{o}}$lder continuous: $|\sqrt x-\sqrt y|\leq\sqrt{|x-y|}$ for $x,y\geq 0$.

Here is my detailed proof of real-valued case.

**Step1.** Let $a=a_0<a_1<\cdots<a_k=b$. Consider $\sum_{j=1}^k|f(a_j)-f(a_{j-1})|^2$. For each $1\leq j\leq k$, if $f(a_j)\cdot f(a_{j-1})\geq 0$, then $|f(a_j)-f(a_{j-1})|=\left||f(a_j)|-|f(a_{j-1})|\right|$; if $f(a_j)\cdot f(a_{j-1})<0$, by IVT, there exists $\xi_j\in(a_{j-1}-a_j)$ such that $f(\xi_j)=0$, so

\begin{align*}
|f(a_j)-f(a_{j-1})|^2&\leq(|f(a_j)-f(\xi_j)|+|f(\xi_j)-f(a_{j-1})|)^2\\
&\leq2|f(a_j)-f(\xi_j)|^2+2|f(\xi_j)-f(a_{j-1})|^2\\
&=2||f(a_j)|-|f(\xi_j)||^2+2||f(\xi_j)|-|f(a_{j-1})||^2.
\end{align*}

Therefore, we have
$$\sum_{j=1}^k|f(a_j)-f(a_{j-1})|^2\leq 2 V_2(|f|;[a,b]).$$
Taking supremum gives that $V_2(f;[a,b])\leq 2V_2(|f|;[a,b])$.

**Step2.** Let $a=a_0<a_1<\cdots<a_k=b$. Since $|\sqrt x-\sqrt y|\leq\sqrt{|x-y|}$ for $x,y\geq 0$, we have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^k||f(a_j)|-|f(a_{j-1})||^2&=\sum_{j=1}^k\left|\sqrt{f^2(a_j)}-\sqrt{f^2(a_{j-1})}\right|^2\\
&\leq\sum_{j=1}^k|f^2(a_j)-f^2(a_{j-1})|\leq V(f^2;[a,b]).
\end{align*}

So $V_2(|f|;[a,b])\leq V(f^2;[a,b])$.

Combining Steps 1 and 2 gives $V_2(f;[a,b])\leq 2V(f^2;[a,b])$ for real-valued $f$.

However, I don't know how to deal with the complex-valued case. I tried to write $f$ in the form of $f=f_r+if_i$, where $f_r$ and $f_i$ are real-valued, and then followed the same ideas as in the proof of real-valued case. But things went to be messy.

This question relates to [another question I asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4463088/m-xi-1-xi2-is-not-a-fourier-multiplier). I want to prove the theorem mentioned in that post:

**Theorem.** If $m\in C(\mathbb R)$ is bouneded such that $m^2$ has bounded variation, then $m$ is an $L^p(\mathbb R)$ Fourier multiplier.

I can prove the theorem for $m$ with $m\in V_2$. Therefore, to finish the proof of the theorem, I only need to show that if $m^2$ is of bounded variation, then $m$ is of bounded quadratic variation, which is exactly this post deals with.

Since in many circumstances, we have to consider comlex-valued multipliers, for example, differential operators. So I want to know the proof of complex-valued functions.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thanks for your comment! I've asked my teacher for the correctness and he said that the original version maybe miss some constants. After I thought a lot more, I've editted the post to a more reader-friendly (I hope so) version.

Comment: @Feng: How did you prove that $V_2(f;[a,b])\leq 2V(f^2;[a,b])$?

Comment: @OliverDíaz I've added my proof for real-valued $f$. I don't know why the 'begin{align*} end{align*}' is broken here. They work well in my Texstuio.

Comment: Oh! They work now! Refreshing the page solves the typing problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to deal with issues related to the choice of argument for $f$ when $f$ has zeroes in $[a,b]$.

Let $a=t_0<\cdots< t_n=b$ be any partition of $[a,b]$ and consider the sum
$$\sum^n_{j=1}|f(t_j)-f(t_{j-1})|^2$$

- If $f(t_j)f(t_{j-1})=0$, then
  $$|f(t_j)-f(t_{j-1})|^2=|f^2(t_j)-f^2(t_{j-1})|$$
- If $f(t_j)f(t_{j-1})\neq0$ and $f$ has a zero $\xi_j\in(t_{j-1},t_j)$, then
  $$|f(t_j)-f(t_{j-1})|^2\leq 2\big(|f^2(t_j)-f^2(\xi_j)|+|f^2(\xi_j)-f^2(t_{j-1})|\big)$$
- Finally, if $f(t_j)f(t_{j-1})\neq0$ and $f$ has no zero in $(t_{j-1},t_j)$, then there is a continuous choice of argument of $f$ in $[t_{j-1},t_j]$, that is, there is a continuous function $\theta:[t_{j-1},t_j]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that
  $$\frac{f(t)}{|f(t)|}=e^{i\theta(t)}\qquad\forall t\in[t_{j-1},t_j]$$
  See this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4246914/121671), for example, which discusses continuous branches of logarithm and argument, or sections 5.4  and 7.2 of Beardon, A. F., *Complex Analysis: The Argument Principle in Analysis and Topology*, John Wiley & Sons. New York, 1979. \

  - If $\Delta_j\theta=\theta(t_j)-\theta(t_{j-1})\in[0,\pi/2]\cup[3\pi/2,2\pi)\mod 2\pi$,  then  the OP's geometric argument in the [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4465279/121671) yields
    $$|f(t_j)-f(t_{j-1})|^2\leq |f^2(t_j)-f^2(t_{j-1})|$$
  - If $\Delta_j\theta\in(\pi/2,3\pi/2)\mod2\pi$, then by continuity of $\theta$, there are  $\xi_1,\xi_2\in(t_{j-1},t_j)$ such that
    $\theta(t_j)-\theta(\xi_2)$, $\theta(\xi_2)-\theta(x_1)$, and $\theta(x_1)-\theta(t_{j-1})$ are in $[0,\pi/2]\cup[3
    p/2,2\pi)\mod 2\pi$. Then,
    $$\begin{align}|f(t_j)-f(t_{j-1})|^2&\leq \big(|f(t_j)-f(\xi_2)|+|f(\xi_2)-f(\xi_1)|+|f(\xi_1)-f(t_{j-1})|\big)^2\\
    &\leq3\Big(|f(t_j)-f(\xi_2)|^2+|f(\xi_2)-f(\xi_1)|^2+|f(\xi_1)-f(t_{j-1})|^2\Big)\\
    &\leq3\Big(|f^2(t_j)-f^2(\xi_1)|+|f^2(\xi_2)-f^2(\xi_1)|+|f^2(\xi_1)-f^2(t_{j-1})|\Big)
    \end{align}
    $$
    by the same geometric argument.

Putting things together, we obtained that
$$V_2(f;[a,b])\leq 3V(f^2;[a,b])$$

Comment: (+1)Thanks for the fantastic answer! And the knowledge about the argument functions! I learn a lot from your answer! Since your answer cites mine, I'll accept your answer but at the same time keep the existence of mine.

Comment: @Feng: Thanks! I added the right section on Beardon's book that discusses continuous arfuemtns and logarithms. It also develops a more general and beautiful notion of index a curve around a point.

Comment: Hello! Sorry to bother you. But I just found that the inequality $|f(t_j)-f(t_{j-1})|^2\leq 2\sum^m_{j=1}|f(t_{j,k})-f(t_{j,k-1})|^2$ does not hold in geenral. I believe this will not be a big problem. Would you mind take some time to rewrite it in a clearer way?

Comment: @Feng: You are right. There is a quick fix however. Again, from the continuity of the argument function $\theta$ on an interval $[t_{j-1}, t_j]$ where $f$ has no zero, if $|\theta(t_j)-\theta(t_{j-1})|\mod\pi$ is larger than $\pi/2$ then we can find a point $\xi\in[t_{j-1},t_j]$ such that $|\theta(\xi)-\theta(t_j)|=\pi/2$. the rest then is as just as before. I will make edits tomorrow in the morning (my local time). best regards

Comment: @Feng: actually, the fix seems to require sometimes two points $\xi_1,\xi_2$. For example, imagine a curve that at $t_{j-1}$ starts at and argument of $0$ (as in your picture) and then moves counterclockwise to an argument between $(\pi,3\pi/2)$. Then two points (instead of just one) would be require to split the the difference $\theta(t_j)-\theta(t_{j-1})$ in three arcs with in-between angle less than $\pi/2$.

Comment: Yes! It seems that we can only get the constant $3$ rather than $2$. Thanks for your patient work!

Answer (score 1):

Now I know how to prove the inequality for complex-valued $f$. Reading again my proof for real-valued $f$ tells me that what I've proved is: for any $-\infty<x<y<+\infty$ we can find $\xi\in[x,y]$ such that
$$|f(x)-f(y)|^2\leq 2\Big(|f^2(x)-f^2(\xi)|+|f^2(\xi)-f^2(y)|\Big). \tag{1}$$
Indeed, inequality $(1)$ also holds for complex-valued functions $f$.

Assume that $f(x)=r_1e^{i\theta_1}$, $f(y)=r_2e^{i\theta_2}$ and $\theta:=\theta_2-\theta_1\in[-\pi,\pi]$.

If $|\theta|\leq \frac\pi2$, then we can easily check that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |f(x)+f(y)|$ (see the picture below for a quick proof), so
$$|f(x)-f(y)|^2\leq |f(x)-f(y)||f(x)+f(y)|=|f^2(x)-f^2(y)|.$$
Taking $\xi=x$ we get $(1)$.

[image]

If $\frac\pi2<|\theta|\leq\pi$, then by the continuity of $f$, there exists $\xi\in[x,y]$ such that
$$f(\xi)\in\left\{re^{i\frac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{2}}: r\in[0,\infty)\right\}.$$
Since $\left|\theta_1-\frac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{2}\right|=\frac{|\theta|}2\leq\frac\pi2$, as before we have $|f(x)-f(\xi)|^2\leq |f^2(x)-f^2(\xi)|$; the same reason implies that $|f(y)-f(\xi)|^2\leq |f^2(y)-f^2(\xi)|.$
So
\begin{align*}
 |f(x)-f(y)|^2&\leq 2\Big(|f(x)-f(\xi)|^2+|f(\xi)-f(y)|^2\Big)\\
 &\leq 2\Big(|f^2(x)-f^2(\xi)|+|f^2(\xi)-f^2(y)|\Big).
\end{align*}
We also get $(1)$.

Finally, let me restate what we have proved: Assume that $f\in C([a,b])$ is a complex-valued function with $V(f^2;[a,b])<\infty$. Then
$$V_2(f;[a,b])\leq 2V(f^2;[a,b]).$$

Comment: (Nice geometric proof! There are a few things that need to be argued. If say $f(x)=0$ or $f(y)=0$ then the argument (the angle $\theta$) is not well defined. In that case of course $|f(x)-f(y)|^2=|f^2(x)-f^2(y)|$.  if $f(x)f(y)\neq0$, then  the issue is that $f$ may have many zeroes in $(x.y)$ so a continuous argument is not well defined.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Thanks for checking my answer! Yes, you're right about the $f(x)f(y)=0$ case. About the case where $f(x)f(y)=0$ and there is a zero point $\xi\in(x,y)$ of $f$, I think I've considered in my answer: note that the set  $\left\{re^{i\frac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{2}}: r\in[0,\infty)\right\}$ contains $0$, which is to say, if $f(\xi)=0$, then we still have $|f(x)-f(y)|^2\leq 2|f(x)-f(\xi)|^2+2|f(\xi)-f(y)|^2=2|f^2(x)-f^2(\xi)|+2|f^2(\xi)-f^2(y)|$.

Comment: I added an argument, based on the existence of continuous arguments for continuous functions $g$ that do not vanish to fix the problem. In any case, your geometric idea removed the main obstacle that I had in my first attempts to your problem. (+1) by the way.